# SQL calculate upgrade rate of fraction

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, aggregate-functions

Given the following two tables

users

```
user_id name    join_date
1       Jon     2020-02-14
2       Jane    2020-02-14
3       Jill    2020-02-15
4       Josh    2020-02-15
5       Jean    2020-02-16
6       Justin  2020-02-17
7       Jeremy  2020-02-18
```

events

```
user_id type access_date
1       F1   2020-03-01
2       F2   2020-03-02
2       P    2020-03-12
3       F2   2020-03-15
4       F2   2020-03-15
1       P    2020-03-16
3       P    2020-03-22
```

return the fraction of users, rounded to two decimal places, who accessed feature two (type: F2 in events table) and upgraded to premium within the first 30 days of signing up.
It should give upgrade_rate 0.33.

Here is my attempt

```
;WITH users AS (
  SELECT * FROM (
    VALUES
        (1, 'Jon', CAST('14-02-20' AS date)), 
        (2, 'Jane', CAST('14-02-20' AS date)), 
        (3, 'Jill', CAST('15-02-20' AS date)), 
        (4, 'Josh', CAST('15-02-20' AS date)), 
        (5, 'Jean', CAST('16-02-20' AS date)), 
        (6, 'Justin', CAST('17-02-20' AS date)),
        (7, 'Jeremy', CAST('18-02-20' AS date))
  ) AS _ (user_id, name, join_date)
),
events AS (
  SELECT * FROM (
    VALUES
        (1, 'F1', CAST('01-03-20' AS date)),
        (2, 'F2', CAST('02-03-20' AS date)), 
        (2, 'P', CAST('12-03-20' AS date)),
        (3, 'F2', CAST('15-03-20' AS date)), 
        (4, 'F2', CAST('15-03-20' AS date)), 
        (1, 'P', CAST('16-03-20' AS date)), 
        (3, 'P', CAST('22-03-20' AS date))
  ) AS _ (user_id, type, access_date)
),
feature_two_upg AS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM events
    WHERE type = 'F2'
),
premium_upg AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM events
    WHERE type = 'P'
),
differ_date AS (
    SELECT feature.user_id, premium.access_date
    FROM feature_two_upg AS feature
    INNER JOIN premium_upg AS premium
    ON feature.user_id = premium.user_id
    WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, feature.access_date, premium.access_date) < 30
)

SELECT ROUND(AVG(CAST(CASE WHEN differ_date.user_id IS NOT NULL THEN 1.0 ELSE 0.0 END AS float)), 2) AS upgrade_rate
FROM users
LEFT JOIN differ_date
ON users.user_id = differ_date.user_id
```

Right now it's giving me 0.29 upgrade_rate and I'm wondering why

Comment: @DaleK sorry, updated

Answer (score 1):

So, I'm checking your query, let's show the result from table without the function

```
SELECT users.user_id, differ_date.user_id
FROM users
LEFT JOIN differ_date
ON users.user_id = differ_date.user_id
```

The result is this

```
users.user_id   differ_date.user_id
1                 NULL
2                   2
3                   3
4                  NULL
5                  NULL
6                  NULL
7                  NULL
```

Now checking your formula, each time the differ_date.user_id is not null you sum 1, the function avg count the 7 register then, is 2 / 7 = 0.28571428, round by 2 = **0.29**

Best Regards

Comment: so it's mistake by the author of this task? i thought i was missing something

Comment: I just tried to help the author to find the answer, for the question "Right now it's giving me 0.29 upgrade_rate and I'm wondering why". regards.

Answer (score 0):

When I run this, I get 0.00, UNLESS I comment out
WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, feature.access_date, premium.access_date) < 30 in differ_date,
Then I get .29.

Comment: Not an answer...

Comment: I don't think that your supplied sample data HAS anyone that meets your .33 Upgrade_Date.
Based on your sample data, can you tell us which users SHOULD meet that criteria? Your sample data is small enough to calculate by hand first.

Comment: I should have added this as a comment, not an answer, sorry, I'm new to this...

Comment: Unfortunately, I can only add comments to my own bad answer.
With your data, if I comment out WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, feature.access_date, premium.access_date) < 30, I also get the 0.28571428 @Diego